# Android app with custom binary files

Tags: android

I have an Android application that initializes by reading in raw binary data that I store in my own binary file format.
Is there a way that I can package this binary info in with application for distribution such as in the resources folder or something? My solution at present has been to just put the files in a folder on the SDCard and open them up for reading. Works for now but for distribution it would be nice to package it all within the APK itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You package it into res/raw folder and read as a Raw resource.

See here for how to deal with raw resources http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: Thanks. Can I directly create a MappedByteBuffer from this?

Comment: You get your raw resource as an InputStream, that is you are simply getting your bytes. I think, anything can be created from that.